# Dynamically capturing heap usage stats collection

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, heap-dump

I want to programatically capture the statistics of java application for all its objects present in heap and their usage.

My requirement is not to analyze the heap dump with MAT, but dynamically take snapshot after every specified period with a breakdown of heap usage by each object present in heap.

Can anybody suggest me any existing APIs if available, over which I can write a wrapper to implement the idea.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, You can take a heap dump programmatically by

```
HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.dumpHeap(fileName, live);
```

then, you can make use of [Memory Analyzer API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php?title=MemoryAnalyzer/Reading_Data_from_Heap_Dumps) to get useful information from the heap dump programmatically